# changing class name without changing style in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I can't disable events on some element (even by element.onclick = null) so I decided to change name of element.
I tried just by:

```
element.className = "newOne";
```

But it made my element dissapear, most probably because it cleared styles.
My second approach included saving styles and then re-copying it to old element:

```
TempStyles = element.styles.cssText;
element.className = "newOne";
element.styles.cssText = tempStyles;
```

I tried both with .cssText and without it, non of them works.
**!!!MY LIMITATIONS ARE IE8 AND NO jQUERY!!!**

Comment: How are you initially adding the events to the specific elements? Please, show sufficient "*[mcve]*" code so that we can reproduce your problem, help with solutions and, quite possibly, point out the errors you may have made that created the problem in the first place.

Comment: have you tried [EventTarget.removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: you could try keeping the old class but append another after it and override?  element.className = "oldClass newOne"; Then override all class styles in the css file using the !important; flag...

Comment: Pete good point, If you just want to remove the event do as Pete suggested.

Comment: I can't use EventListener's because ie8 does not support it, only attachEvent/detachEvent but some process is overiding it all the time. All I need to know is mentioned in the title

Comment: What you ask in the title will not solve the problem, changing the class name won't remove the event handler, and will - unless you clone all the applied styles of your element - change the presentation. If you show us the details we've asked for then we might be able to help solve the problem, rather than trying to solve the wrong problem that appears to be the result of a misunderstanding.

Comment: script which generate other events generats itself from dll file and I have no idea how to get it. I'm working on tool delivered by telerik, I don't think you ever hear about it.

Answer (score -1):

If you previously attributed a class to that HTML element, doing `element.className = "newOne"` will replace all your other classes with `newOne`, as well as any styles associated with them.

If you want to maintain you old classes and respective styles, you must append the new class to your HTML element:

```
element.className += " newOne";
```

Note that extra space before the new class name. It is needed to separate the new class name from the previous, so the property will hold `oldClass newOne` and not `oldClassnewOne`. That way, your element has now two classes.

Comment: thx for help, but I need to change class name to prevent even from using it, so the old name must be erased.

Comment: @Arkadiusz sorry, I misunderstood the question. Can you please upload some code to https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar, in order to understand better what you are trying to achieve and what are you getting?